# Will wearing multiple fire protection armor pieces stack their effects?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm digging into the Minecraft enchantment system, and looking at the wiki, I see the same type of protection can't be on the same armor type – but what about different armors? More importantly to me, can I wear several of the same kind of protection (fire, projectile, blasting) on different pieces and stack the protection effects? Does it follow that wearing 4 pieces of high valued fire protection will make me almost immune to fire damage? Or will I just get the effects of the best one with the rest going to waste?

Comment: I'm only guessing here but wouldn't they each give that part of the body the percentage their single enchantment is. So for instance Blasting. If you have Blasting I on your helmet then only explosion vectors that hit to your head are reduced. That would make sense to me.

Comment: @Glued Since when do all games make sense? :P (Jokes aside, I *highly* doubt Minecraft works that way)

Comment: @GluedHands Is MC's collision detection that sophisticated?

Comment: @fredley it isn't. Aside from the Enderdragon, all mobs (players included) have only a single hitbox.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which configuration of armor enchantments gives maximum protection?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/102707/which-configuration-of-armor-enchantments-gives-maximum-protection)

Answer (score 25):

Yes, fire protection stacks.  To test this, I put on a diamond helmet with Fire Protection I and stood in fire.  Then, I put on an entire suit of diamond armor with Fire Protection I and went to stand in the fire again.  I took no damage, though my armor took extensive damage.

This is the video I made in the process (I'm not sure I've properly annotated it, but hopefully you can tell what I'm doing.  :P):

Comment: Very nice demonstration. +50 reps for you!

Comment: Is the effect you are seeing from the Fire Protection or from the damage reduction from the diamond armor?

Comment: @Jim Except KevinY isn't the author of the question, so he can't do that :)

Comment: Maybe. [Here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52455/do-armor-enchantments-stack?lq=1)

Answer (score 5):

They definitely stack, I just tested them. You're pretty much immune to fire with two diamond pieces of fire IV if your hunger bar is full.