# Do armor enchantments stack?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have diamond helmet/chest piece/legs with protection 2 or 3 on each one. I'm wondering if there's any point to wearing all at the same time or would I be better off just wearing one piece with the highest enchant and the rest regular, unenchanted, diamond?

Comment: none told you must to wear armor.

Comment: The original question was not a duplicate, as it specifically asked about protection enchants. If protection enchants and fire protection enchants act the same, then I agree, this is a duplicate.

Comment: I am not saying this must be closed as a duplicate, but protection enchants in Minecraft work in the same way, only differing by protection level and damage types (specific enchantments, like Fire Protection, absorb a larger percentage of damage than generic Protection, but only of a single damage type).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The protection enchantment only applies to that piece of armor, so while they don't "stack" with one piece affecting other pieces, wearing a full set of protection IV protects you more than wearing just one piece.

Comment: That sounds perfectly logical.

Comment: Is this still accurate?

Comment: Yep. Also adding type-specific enchantments on the same piece of armor like blast protection IV + protection IV will protect you more than just protection IV. The total damage reduction from all of your armor + enchantments is capped at 80% of incoming damage.