# What are the specific effects of hidden armor bonuses in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

There are four possible general armor enchantments available in Minecraft v1.6.x:

1. **Protection**
2. **Fire Protection**
3. **Blast Protection**
4. **Projectile Protection**

As discussed [elsewhere](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/102707/which-configuration-of-armor-enchantments-gives-maximum-protection), stacking different enchantment levels of these on different pieces of armor can maximize the damage reduction from different damage sources (general, fire, explosions, arrows, etc.).  However, wiki sources also mention that Fire Protection additionally reduces the time spent aflame, and Blast Protection reduces the knockback from explosions.

Does Projectile Protection reduce the knockback from projectiles?

Additionally, does the knockback reduction offered by armor enchantments and the burn time reduction offered by Fire Protection scale with the enchantment levels, and is there a cap?

What is a specific explanation of the complete effects afforded by these enchantments, beyond the EPF damage reduction values?

Comment: I'll do some science on this tonight. I know the burn time reduction is true, but I'm not sure about knockback reduction. The science never lies, though.

Comment: @Unionhawk You seem to not have gotten to the point of science yet. Mind doing some tonight (EU-time)?

Comment: @Arperum Some real-life science has gotten in the way thus far... Can probably work something out in chat, or something?

Comment: Any update on burn time reduction?

Answer (score 1):

No, Projectile Protection does not reduce knock-back from projectiles.

Yes, Fire Protection's burn time reduction scales with the level. And there isn't a cap.

**Explanation:**

1. Protection: Reduces damage from most sources, nothing else.
2. Fire Protection: Reduces damage from fire AND reduces burn duration.
3. Blast Protection: Reduces damage from explosion AND reduces knock-back from explosions.
4. Projectile Protection: Reduces damage from projectiles(ex. fireballs), nothing else