# Which buff offers better protection?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft I have a Blast Protection 4 on a diamond chest plate and another diamond chest plate with Protection 3. Which one is better? By the way this armor is going to be used Battling the Wither, the Ender dragon, and the Elder guardian.

Comment: i think [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/103068/30879) may help you since the underlining reason for your question is trying to get the best protection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can compare the two directly. One reduces *all* damage, whereas the other *only* reduces blast damage and knockback.

If you're asking specifically "Which one is best for which boss", it depends on what kind of damage they deal.

- The Wither deals mainly blast damage, therefore Blast protection would be best.
- The Ender dragon deals basic damage, so Protection would be better, because there is no explosions.

Your best bet is honestly combining the two.

Answer (score 0):

There is really no way in which to say which is better. The simple idea is Blast Protection does the following:

- Protects you from **Blast** damage
- Reduces **Knockback** from blasts

Protection on the other hand, does this:

- Protects you from **most forms of damage** (**Including** Blast Damage)
- However, **not damage from the Void or /kill**

In conclusion, if you were taking on those bosses, Normal Protection will be your best bet as it would protect you from all of their attacks. Except the Wither's poison.